# How are request parameters mapped into RenderingModel of magnolia?

Tags: freemarker, url-parameters, magnolia

Im using Magnolia `RenderingModel` in combination with Freemarker. 
I have URLs like the following:

```
http://anyPath/context?productTypes=XXXXX&productTypes=YYYYY
```

my rendering model class looks like:

```
 class MyModel extends RenderingModelImpl {
   ...
   private String[] productTypes;
   ...
 }
```

However the mentioned array contains only the first value, but not the second.
I checked the behaviour of template directives like `ctx.getParameters()`. This shows the same behaviour, I get only the first value returned. But if im using `ctx.getParameterValues(paramName)`, it returns both values.

This leads me to following questions:

- How would I go, if I want to lookup how the request parameters are mapped into the rendering model, or better:
- How can i change the behaviour of that ?
- Can anyone acknowledge, that this behaviour is wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It used to be mentioned in documentation and I believe it still is - if you use `.getParameters()` you get only first value for multivalue parameter. If you want to get all the values, you need to use `.getParameterValues(String param)`.

From what I understand reasons for that were backward compatibility.

As for changing the behavior, you would need to write your own renderer (e.g. by extending default `FreemarkerRenderer` and override `info.magnolia.rendering.renderer.AbstractRenderer.newModel(Class<T>, Node, RenderableDefinition, RenderingModel<?>)` method which instantiates and populates the model class.

Alternatively you can provide fix for above set population method and submit it to Magnolia as a patch. While the `.getParameters()` behavior is iirc on purpose, the model param population might not be, so you have high chance of getting that changed.